# On parents' similarity

Tags: human-genetics, epigenetics

I don't know if this is a real claim, I live in Mexico City and most of the people I know are more similar to their father than to their mother? Why is that? Are the x and y cromosomes somehow related to the strength of a particular gen?

Comment: It doesn't look like a proper claim. Unless you can support it with verifiable data it's just your opinion.

Comment: Good observation:  http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2977710/People-genetically-like-fathers-mothers-Scientists-discover-use-paternal-DNA.html

Comment: Well then, now we have a source, so which characteristics make the father's genes stronger?